# Using AMD BLIS / Lapack in R

Tags: r, lapack, blas, amd-processor

I'm a lucky owner of AMD Ryzen 5950x processor. I use `R` for different calculations, so, earlier I had an Intel processor and a simpliest solution of starting using Intel BLAS / Lapack was a copying and renaming of some libraries (dll) in R directory.
I have AOCL libraries installed on my computer, but still have no information how to get married `R` with `AOCL`. Could anyone explain what should I do or (it will be the best variant) someone has an instruction how to add `AOCL` libraries directly in `R` or, maybe, build `R` with these libraries?

Thank you.

P.S. I use gcc 12.2.0 on Windows 11.
P.P.S. Do not say me to use OpenBLAS, because OpenBLAS has a big problem with freezing execution in parallel calculations, unfortunately.

Comment: I found one way how to do this under Windows. You need to install AOCL for Windows form AMD site, after that you should go to the folder "{Installation path}/amd-blis/lib/lp64". In this folder you can find "AOCL-LibBlis-Win-dll.dll" - copy it to the path where current "Rblas.dll" exists. Rename older "Rblas.dll" to any other name, rename "AOCL-LibBlis-Win-dll.dll" to "Rblas.dll". You also need to perform the same action for  "AOCL-LibFlame-Win-dll.dll" (to "Rlapack.dll"). Check that you have also "libiomp5md.dll" and "libiompstubs5md.dll"  in your "Rblas.dll" folder.

Comment: But of course, this is lifehack and not fully completed solution.

Answer (score 1):

Dmitriy's method didn't work for me (I didn't know where to find the omp libraries), but an updated version of this one (https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1mrrE8nLx1Morsy0CSejSWSavatS-PyxNJMWSxZ5M_MI/edit#slide=id.gf104e05a_048) did:

1. download AMD's AOCL and install (https://www.amd.com/en/developer/aocl.html#downloads)
2. copy all the files in these directories (or wherever you installed AOCL):

- C:\Program Files\AMD\AOCL-Windows\amd-blis\lib\LP64
- C:\Program    Files\AMD\AOCL-Windows\amd-libflame\lib\LP64

to the folder where R's Rblas is. In my case:

- C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.1\bin\x64

3. in that destination folder, rename these two to ...old (or similar) so you can easily change back:

- Rblas.dll
- Rlapack.dll

4. use those two names (Rblas.dll and Rlapack.dll) to rename these two files which you've just put in the folder:

- AOCL-LibBlis-Win-MT-dll.dll
- AOCL-LibFlame-Win-MT-dll.dll

5. download and install vcredist_x64.exe (https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe)
   [note: I didn't need this step, as I already had MS Visual Studio installed]
6. in Windows Settings, search for 'Edit environment variables for your account'; click 'New' in the dialogue box that appears (top panel); add:

- OMP_NUM_THREADS

and

- x

(where x is the number of cores) in the input boxes.

7. restart and use R

I don't know whether steps 5) and 6) are crucial but I did them and it worked. I have a AMD Ryzen 9 3900X with 12 cores and 24 threads. For x (step 6), I used the number of cores (=12), as it was actually slower when I tried with the number of threads. The explanation seems to be here: https://illposed.net/r-on-linux.html.

I haven't done any speed testing but, at the times all cores are activated, it seems to be about 30% faster than it was before.

Comment: @M C yu do need to add libiomp5md.dll from Intel MKL or get libomp.dll from mingw , copy it to the forled with Rblas.dll, Rlapack.dll and name it as libiomp5md.dll

Comment: @M C also you shouldn't use MT version of AMD libraries. I don't know why, but htis method doesn't work with MT libraries version.

Comment: @M C also you do need to use only LP64 version of libraries, not ILP64.